# onFocus and onBlur events for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to handle the `onFocus` and `onBlur` events for 2 elements - the `input` and the `textarea` elements. I even tried to implement it as one state with the object but it's just not possible, so I separated it into two states. Whenever I try to focus on the textarea, it'll expand, however, if I start focusing on the `input` element, it'll collapse instead of staying expanded. How do I implement this?

```
  const [titleFocused, setTitleFocus] = useState(null);
  const [contentFocused, setContentFocus] = useState(null);
  
  function handleFocus(event) {
    const {name} = event.target;

    setTitleFocus(name === 'title' && true);
    setContentFocus(name === 'content' && true);
  }

  function handleUnfocus(event) {
    const {name} = event.target;

    setTitleFocus(name === 'title' && false);
    setContentFocus(name === 'content' && false);
  }

  return (
    <div >
      <form 
          className="create-note">
        {titleFocused || contentFocused && (
          <input
          name="title"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={note.title}
          placeholder="Title"
          onFocus={handleFocus}
          onBlur={handleUnfocus}
          />)
        }
        <textarea
          name="content"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={note.content}
          placeholder="Take a note..."
          onFocus={handleFocus}
          onBlur={handleUnfocus}
          rows={titleFocused || contentFocused ? "3" : "1"}
        />
        <Zoom in={titleFocused || contentFocused} appear={true}>
          <Fab onClick={submitNote}>
            <AddIcon fontSize="large" />
          </Fab>
        </Zoom>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably caused by event handles toggling both states even when the event is not concerning the component.

This should work

```
function handleFocus(event) {
    const {name} = event.target;
    name === 'title' && setTitleFocus(true);
    name === 'content' && setContentFocus(true);
 }

 function handleUnfocus(event) {
    const {name} = event.target;
    name === 'title' && setTitleFocus(false);
    name === 'content' && setContentFocus( false);
 }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, Is my implementation correct? I think the problem is the logic

Comment: By expanding, do you mean that text area gets more rows, because of this line:

rows={titleFocused || contentFocused ? "3" : "1"}

Comment: Or whatever the Zoom component does?

Comment: Yes, expanding the text area as well as showing the input for the title and the submit button from the Zoom material.